# Number of elements in an iterator

Tags: r, iterator

I'm using the `isplit` command from the `iterators` pacakge to loop over a data frame. Does anyone know if it's possible to get the number of elements in iterator?

E.g.,

```
library(iterators)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(letters[1:26], 100, replace = TRUE), b = runif(100))
df.iter <- isplit(df, df$a, drop = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to convert it to a `list` with `as.list` (similar to `list(generator)` in python and get the `length` of it

```
length(as.list(df.iter))
#[1] 26
```

which is equal to the `length` from `split`

```
length(split(df, df$a, drop = TRUE))
#[1] 26
```

Comment: this works great for the sample, but my data has 6 million rows. i've been waiting about 5 minute and it still hasn't return. i know how to efficiently compute the number i think there should be, but i want to confirm that i got the isplit command correct. hence the desired to check the length of the iterator.

Comment: @rrs If you want to do a group by operation, `tidyverse` or `data.table` would be very effficient

Comment: I agree, but I'm using this in a parallel `foreach` loop.